# extract string from rows using awk based on string value

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I have a text file with data as:

```
(832555,488012,0,17:31:32.541,2014-08-06 17:31:32.000,0,0,NULL,FBCD,"-6484620512517810993"etcetcetc
```

I want to extract the string post `FBCD` so my output should be:

```
FBCD,"-6484620512517810993"etcetc
```

I am able to find the position of `FBCD` using `awk`:

```
awk '{print substr("FBCD",1,200)}' file.txt
```

but I cannot extract the remaining values.

Comment: Substr doesnt work like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USing awk With substr

```
awk '{print substr($0,index($0,"FBCD"),200)' file
```

Using sed

```
sed -e 's/^.*\(FBCD.\{200\}\).*/\1/' file
```

If you want it till the end of the line

```
    awk '{print substr($0,index($0,"FBCD"))' file

    sed -e 's/^.*\(FBCD\)/\1/' file
```

Comment: +1 but I don't think the `,200` is useful. I think the OP was using that as just some large value to get the rest of the line because he didn't know that's what he'd get by just leaving that argument empty.

Comment: @EdMorton Edited in case that is what he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes: `substr("FBCD",1,200)`

will cut the input string from char `1` - `200`. but you gave `FBCD` as input string, and `FBCD` has only length `4`, that's why you got  only `FBCD`.

In fact, `grep` was born to extract things,  would this help you?

```
grep -oE 'FBCD.{1,196}' file
```

Comment: "grep was born to extract strings" - that may be debatable since the `-o` option to `grep` that you're using to extract is not in POSIX

Comment: @kent you have used a backtick instead of a quote

Comment: @Jidder oh, yes, I didn't test, was a typo, confused with markdown code block.... thanks.

Comment: @1_CR is correct, grep was born to print the line containing a regexp (g/re/p). These days the GNU guys have their version of it recursively searching for files, cooking breakfast and all sorts of other things. I'm on the fence about whether `-o` was a good idea but at least it's not obviously a bad idea (unlike trying to do `find`s job).

Comment: @EdMorton so I should say grep was born to extract lines.. :)

Comment: grep was born to print lines that match a regexp. extract is an ambiguous word since it could mean select or remove (If I extract a tooth it's gone from the body but present in the surgical tray so whether that's selecting it or removing it depends on whether you're the body or the tray) so it's best avoided. If I say I want to extract a line from an input stream I might mean I want to only be left with that line or it might mean I want to be left with everything other than that line.